# Storing and reading large arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm recreating the level data structure for my 2D game. Previously I've used large 2D byte arrays for the levels and therefore I was able to keep them inside the memory without any problems, but now as I'm expanding the game and I cannot store all the data inside memory. So I've recreated the level structure like this.

Code for a single tile:

```
public class Tile {

    public static final int SIZE = 16;

    private short id;
    private short health;
    private boolean solid;

    ...
}
```

Instead of storing all the tiles into one single array, I split the large array into smaller arrays - chunks:

```
public class Chunk {

    public static final int WIDTH = 16;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 16;

    private Tile[][] tiles;

    private int chunkX;
    private int chunkY;

    ... 
}
```

And finally where I keep the chunks:

```
public class Map {

    public static final int EXTRA_DRAW_WIDTH = 0;
    public static final int EXTRA_DRAW_HEIGHT = 0;

    private Chunk[][] chunks;

    private int width;
    private int height;

    ...
}
```

The problem I am facing now is that I can't figure out on how to properly store these chunks onto the disk and later on read them one by one as I traverse the level (I want to load only the nearest chunks to the game entities). So far I have tried:

- Store each chunk in a separate file. However for larger worlds the file count became way too big, for example 4096 (I have to keep the chunks of small size in order to update as least game entities as possible).
- Store all chunks into a single text file, though I could not figure out a fast way on how to get the specific chunks I need.
- I've looked into [Fast-serialization](http://ruedigermoeller.github.io/fast-serialization/) but couldn't work out on how to read only specific chunks from the file as well. I also ran into some memory problems when using Fast-serialization and Serialization.

Ideally I'd like to have all the chunks inside a single file and so that I could easily specify which ones to load. Are there any libraries or specific methods of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can ensure that every `Tile` and every `Chunk` has the same size on disk, you can map a `Chunk` directly onto a certain position in your file.

Example:

```
SeekableByteChannel channel;
ByteBuffer chunkBuffer;

public void open(Path path) {
    channel = Files.newByteChannel(path, EnumSet.of(READ, WRITE, SPARSE)));
    chunkBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Chunk.SIZE);
}

public void close() {
    channel.close();
    chunkBuffer = null;
}

public void write(Chunk chunk) {
    int index = chunkIndex(chunk.getX(), chunk.getY());
    chunkBuffer.clear();
    chunk.saveInto(chunkBuffer);
    chunkBuffer.flip();
    channel.position(HEADER_SIZE + Chunk.SIZE * index);
    channel.write(chunkBuffer);
}

public Chunk read(int x, int y) {
    int index = chunkIndex(x, y);
    chunkBuffer.clear();
    channel.position(HEADER_SIZE + Chunk.SIZE * index);
    if (channel.read(chunkBuffer) < 0) {
        /* end-of-file or chunk at given index not written yet */
        return null;
    } else {
        chunkBuffer.flip();
        return Chunk.loadFrom(chunkBuffer);
    }
}

/** compute linar index of chunk at position x/y */
private int chunkIndex(int x, int y) {
    return y * MAX_CHUNKS_X + x;
}
```

Saving and loading `Chunk` objects:

```
public class Chunk {
    public static final int WIDTH = 16;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 16;
    public static final int SIZE = WIDTH * HEIGHT * Tile.SIZE;

    private Tile[][] tiles;

    public void saveInto(ByteBuffer buf) {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x) { 
            for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y) {
                tiles[x][y].saveInto(buf);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Chunk loadFrom(ByteBuffer buf) {
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk();
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x) { 
            for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y) {
                tiles[x][y] = Tile.loadFrom(buf);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Saving and loading `Tile` objects:

```
public class Tile {
    public static final int SIZE = 16;

    private short id;
    private short health;
    private boolean solid;

    public void saveInto(ByteBuffer buf) {
        buf.putShort(id);
        buf.putShort(health);
        buf.put(solid ? 1 : 0);
        ...
        // make sure to always write the same tile size!
        // fill up with placeholder if necessary!
    }

    public static Tile loadFrom(ByteBuffer buf) {
        Tile tile = new Tile();
        tile.id = buf.getShort();
        tile.health = buf.getShort();
        tile.solid = buf.get() == 1;
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course you might add some range checks and proper exception handling!

Comment: Is HEADER_SIZE variable in case I add some extra data for the map before everything else? If I ignore that variable everything seems to work fine, except the file is huge, saving only one chunk generates a  1.25KB file. Maybe there is some way I could apply compression onto this?

Comment: I've figured out the size problem, Tile.SIZE = 16 is meant for drawing, I created a different variable DATA = 5, for each byte in the Tile class. Although for more chunks the size is still quite large so I'm still looking for compression method.

Comment: I think you should add a header to your game file which holds some meta-information, e.g. version number, total sizes (in case, size may vary), total time played, current player position/heading, etc.

Comment: How many chunks do you expect? Or: How big is your game world?

Comment: The game could have up to 8192 x 2048 tiles. So that is 512 x 128 chunks (if the chunk size is 16). Though I think I found a mistake, instead of sending chunk index to the chunkIndex method, I was sending chunk coordinates which resulted in writing a lot of empty space in the file, now the file sizes seem to be accurate and small.

Comment: 8192 x 2048 tiles with 5 bytes per tile makes 80 mb file size in total. Not that huge. And still not too large to fit in memory.

Comment: Yes that is not a lot, but I plan to expand the tile class so it could be a problem later on. Also on the memory side, I've been playing around with this a bit more, and I noticed that the used memory increases by almost three times if I read more and more chunks and is not freed. Does the ByteBuffer keep the objects inside the memory after reading them?

Comment: Yes it does, but a `ByteBuffer` does not grow, and because you've got only one small `ByteBuffer` for just one `Chunk`, this is not a problem. Don't worry about memory consumption too much, as long as you don't get an `OutOfMemoryError`. The JVM will consume as much memory as it gets.